# Increased Moving Averages

Tags: python, function, numpy, machine-learning, finance

I want to calculate the increased moving averages.

My main aim is to get increased MAs, such that first MA is average of first value, next MA is Average of first 2 values, next MA is Average of first 4 values, next MA is Average of first 6 values and so on.

How can I do this using numpy library in Python?

I am doing my analysis on time series data using Python. I am also interested in moving averages, to calculate moving averages for my target variable, I used the following function to calculate MA over my target variable.

```
def movingaverage(values, avg_number):
    weights = np.repeat(1.0, avg_number)/avg_number
    smas = np.convolve(values, weights, 'valid')
    return smas
```

In this function, I supply my pandas Series and the average number to calc. corresponding averages.

Now, I want to calculate increased moving averages. like in the above the averages are being calculated over fixed number, say 90.

But, in case of reduced/increased moving averages, this number will reduce/increase at each next value.

My main aim is to get increased MAs, such that first MA is average of first value, next MA is Average of first 2 values, next MA is Average of first 4 values, next MA is Average of first 6 values and so on.

How can I do this using numpy library in Python?

If input is `[1,5,3,6,8,4,6,8,4,2,3,5,8,6,4]` and output will be increased moving averages like `[1,3,3,3.75....]`

Comment: Have you looked at `pd.Series.rolling(...).mean()` ?

Comment: @JonClements, I know about it, but it gives constant moving averages as the numpy based function above.

Comment: Adding sample input and sample output will also be helpful

Comment: Is this different from your previous one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857129/?

Comment: @Divakar no it isnt , so you have any idea about it?

Comment: @Bharathshetty 
The input can be a list of values such as [1,5,3,6,8,4,6,8,4,2,3,5,8,6,4] and output will be increased moving averages like [1,3,3,3.75....]

Comment: Hope my answer helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` and `np.arange` i.e

```
x = np.array([1,5,3,6,8,4,6,8,4,2,3,5,8,6,4])
y = x.cumsum()/np.arange(1,len(x)+1)
```

Output :

```
array([ 1.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,  3.75      ,  4.6       ,
     4.5       ,  4.71428571,  5.125     ,  5.        ,  4.7       ,
     4.54545455,  4.58333333,  4.84615385,  4.92857143,  4.86666667])
```

Comment: I have a question, now, if I want to make averages instead of steps of 1 to 2. like first moving average is average of first values,next is avg of 2 values, nect is average of 4 values, how can I do that. TIA

Comment: Just this question, please make an edit in your answer.

Comment: Thats called rolling mean.

Comment: y must be like this : 

1, 3, 3.75, 4.5, 5.125 etc.

Comment: Im bit confused now how did you get the values like this. Can you elaborate a bit

Comment: Its just the every second value of y. if x = n elements, y will have n/2 elements

Comment: Shiv Im still not gettting like find mean of every 2 values then find rolling mean again?

Comment: It is like, y.tolist()[::2]

But, my idea is I need a function that can create rolling means, here, you did for adding one value at each iteration the get the next, but here I want to add 2 values at each iteration, and the function should create that based on n, whether it is 2 or 3 or 4...

Comment: I had the solution until I faced a array with odd number of elements

Comment: That is what I want

Comment: you can share that.

Comment: `new = x[:-1]` `k = (new[::2] + new[1:][::2])` `k.cumsum()/len(k)` this is all I cound think. I neglect the last value of x since there are odd number of elements